# Problems installing Mayavi to Anaconda (Windows)

Tags: python, anaconda, mayavi

I'm using Anaconda and want to install the mayavi modul. It doesn't work though, no matter if I use the conda or pip commands. If I use the conda command I get this:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - mayavi -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

If I use the pip command I get this but then nothing happens:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: mayavi
  Building wheel for mayavi (setup.py) ... \
```

I know other people also faced some issues installing mayavi, though until now no solution has worked for me. If someone has an a idea that could help, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The python version you have in that environment seems to be incompatible. Have you tried creating a new env with `conda create -n envName -c conda-forge python mayavi`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you. You can install in your terminal the package as .whl

Go to this site: [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mayavi) and search (Strg + F) for you package (mayavi). Click on the link with your python version.
The file will automaticaly download. Then type in your terminal

```
pip install <path_of_downloaded_file>
```

The name of the .whl file is as example:

```
mayavi‑4.7.1+vtk82‑cp<your_version>‑cp<your_version>‑win_amd64.whl
```

NOTE: only works on windows